# Is NLog 4.4.11 usable with a dotnet core 1.1 application?

Tags: .net-core, nlog

I have a dotnet core 1.1 application (In VS, targets .NETCoreApp 1.1).  I can't install NLog 4.4.11 via NuGet because it has a dependency on dotnet framework.  Nuget reports the following:

```
Package NLog 4.4.11 is not compatible with netcoreapp1.1    
(.NETCoreApp,Version=v1.1). Package NLog 4.4.11 supports:
  - monoandroid10 (MonoAndroid,Version=v1.0)
  - net35 (.NETFramework,Version=v3.5)
  - net40 (.NETFramework,Version=v4.0)
  - net45 (.NETFramework,Version=v4.5)
  - sl4 (Silverlight,Version=v4.0)
  - sl5 (Silverlight,Version=v5.0)
  - wp8 (WindowsPhone,Version=v8.0)
  - xamarinios10 (Xamarin.iOS,Version=v1.0)
```

So far so good.

However, NLog.Extensions.Logging (https://github.com/NLog/NLog.Extensions.Logging) is supposed to work against dotnet core, so I installed it.  In VS 2017, this project includes NLog 4.4.11 as a dependency.

This is confusing because I can't use NLog directly, but can at one remove?

Anyone have some insight on this?

Comment: NLog 5.0 BETA is the only version with native support for Net Core: https://www.nuget.org/packages/NLog/5.0.0-beta09

Answer (score 1):

For .NET Core 1 you need the betas of NLog 5.

The confusing part is here that ASP.NET Core can **also** run on the full .NET framework (e.g. .NET 4.6).

The NLog.Extensions.Logging is meant for ASP.NET Core and .NET Core console applications, hence this one works also for ASP.NET Core when running on the full .NET framework.

Answer (score 0):

You could consider an option to add a `Standard 2.0` library project between logging with `NLog` and your projects you'd like to log from.

In brief the scheme is the following:

- `Standard-2-Project` - wraps logging component and has dependency to `NLog 4.4.11` package
- `NET-4-Project-A` - uses `Standard-2-Project` for logging
- `NET-4-Project-B` - uses `Standard-2-Project` for logging
- `NET-Core-Project-C` - uses `Standard-2-Project` for logging
- `NET-Core-Project-D` - uses `Standard-2-Project` for logging
- `...`  - uses `Standard-2-Project` for logging

Hope that helps.